# Are these [performance] questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-topic

These two questions were posted by the same user, in August - the user joined CR around that time:

- [Capture with User32.dll or hook?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29424/capture-with-user32-dll-or-hook)
- [Encoding a screenshot to JPEG and saving it to a memorystream](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29548/encoding-a-screenshot-to-jpeg-and-saving-it-to-a-memorystream)

Both have to do with capturing screenshots at lightning speed. There *is* code in the post, but the OP's focus isn't about the code and getting it reviewed, it's strictly about getting the thing to run faster.

The reason I'm asking here is because I simply can't make up my mind about those. They are:

- Not exactly duplicates, since they don't involve the same code, at least it's not obvious.
- Probably off-topic for SO, since the code isn't broken.
- Not exactly asking for code to be written, but I find they're sitting on the fence.
- Not exactly asking for code to be reviewed.

Could they be good migration prospects for Programmers.SE? Or are they on-topic here on CR?

Answer (score 3):

Both questions are too old for migration, so that possibility is out.  It's also hard to tell if they're dupes (not *exact* dupes, obviously), and they may not be.  Other than that, they look on-topic enough here.  As they have been around awhile without much attention, possibly due to the complexity of the code and/or request, I suppose they can just be closed as *unclear what you're asking*.

If someone here wishes to review them, then that's alright.  If not, then someone can flag/vote-to-close them as such to put them in the close queue for others to decide on, or flag a moderator with a custom message for immediate closure (if it seems necessary).